# How to generate a CSR for Verisign for use with FileZilla (in Windows)

Tags: ssl-certificate, ftps, csr

I need to get a certificate from VeriSign to use in FileZilla (FTPS, FTP over SSL), to get the certificate, Verisign asks for a CSR file, FileZilla doesn't seem to have a way to generate those CSR files; how would I go about generating this file that VeriSign needs so they can issue a certificate that I can use in FileZilla?

Comment: Are you looking for a client certificate or a server certificate? "FileZilla" doesn't use certificates per-se, the FTPS protocol does, so if you're hosting an FTPS server, then it's your FTPS daemon that needs the certificate, not FileZilla. Your question here http://serverfault.com/questions/151501/ssl-certificate-for-ftps-is-it-the-same-as-for-https seems to get it correct

Comment: server certificate, FileZilla does have the option to import the certificate, and you can generate one too, but I need it from a CA, and for that I need the CSR

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use something like `openssl` to generate a Certificate Signing Request. It is not too difficult to do and there are plenty of instructions on how to do it on the internet.

```
openssl genrsa -out host.key 2048
openssl req -new -nodes -key host.key -out host.csr
```

Or something to that affect.

Comment: +1, Google: http://www.google.com/search?q=openssl+csr

Comment: IIS has a tool to generate CSRs, could I use that? FileZilla only needs the certificate, doesn't care about the CSR, that makes me think it would work, but I'd like to know for sure

Comment: After the certificate is generated, you would only need the certificate itself and the private key. The CSR itself is not needed.